# show create table return b"CREATE TABLE

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Same code in different mysql database instance

```
sql_table_def = 'show create table {}.{}'.format(dbname,table_name)
df_table_def = pandas.read_sql_query(sql_table_def,self.conn)
create_table_sql = df_table_def.head(1)['Create Table'].values[0]
```

But sometimes the returned value is strange:

```
print(create_table_sql)
b"CREATE TABLE
```

There is a b in front of `"CREATE TABLE"`!

but most of the db instance 's return is right:

```
 print(create_table_sql)
```

Just return `"CREATE TABLE"`, no b in front.

What's the problem?

Comment: What is it you are changing between instances? All are mysql? what is different? (I wonder if one is not utf-8 encoded!)

Comment: no change between instances,if I show session's variables,the character set are all set to UTF8;all are mysql

Comment: I think i'd just do: `create_table_sql.decode("utf-8") if isinstance(create_table_sql, bytes) else create_table_sql` ...

Comment: yes ,this is a most simple solution ^_^

Answer (score 0):

The b prefix shows that it's a [`bytes`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes) object rather than a [`str`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str).
You can convert `bytes` to a `str` using .decode (if you know the encoding):

```
In [11]: b'string'
Out[11]: b'string'

In [12]: b'string'.decode("utf-8")  # the encoding may not be utf-8...
Out[12]: 'string'

In [13]: type(b'string')
Out[13]: bytes

In [14]: type('')
Out[14]: str
```

The issue is the the database doesn't know the encoding and doesn't guess (which is probably a good thing). Although you may find that encodings other than utf-8 are not supported (e.g. for [PyMySQL](https://github.com/PyMySQL/mysqlclient-python/issues/210#issuecomment-345190385))...

Comment: So - reading the question again - my bet is that it's engine specific, which is kinda interesting.

Comment: It works :)      but I have set 'utf8' on connect, and if I show variables like '%character_set%';the session's output is also utf8,why some instances return str,some return bytes,   conn=MySQLdb.connect(
                host=dbhost,
                user=dbuser,
                passwd=dbpassword,
                port=dbport,
                db=dbname,charset='utf8'